# Remove duplicates from column

Tags: perl, awk, sed

I would like to remove duplicate lines in a file (duplicates of column 2) keeping the complete first line for each duplicate.

Example input:

```
10.4.14.1,201s-1-S
10.4.16.1,201s-1-S
10.4.17.1,40-MDF-S
10.4.18.1,201s-1-S
10.4.19.1,201s-1-S
10.4.20.1,201s-1-S
10.4.21.1,201s-1-S
10.4.22.1,201s-1-S
10.4.23.1,201s-1-S
10.4.24.1,MDF-S
```

Desired result:

```
10.4.14.1,201s-1-S
10.4.17.1,40-MDF-S
10.4.24.1,MDF-S
```

So far I have tried

```
awk '!k[$5]++' file
```

and

```
awk '!_[$5]++' file
```

but this does not yield my desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using a perl one-liner

```
perl -aF, -lne 'print if ! $seen{$F[1]}++' data.txt
```

Outputs:

```
10.4.14.1,201s-1-S
10.4.17.1,40-MDF-S
10.4.24.1,MDF-S
```

#### Explanation:

**Switches**:

- `-a`: Splits the line on space and loads them in an array `@F`
- `-F/pattern/`: split() pattern for `-a` switch (`//`'s are optional)
- `-l`: Enable line ending processing
- `-n`: Creates a `while(<>){..}` loop for each line in your input file.
- `-e`: Tells `perl` to execute the code on command line.

Comment: Unless you hate using `unless` which means not doing `perl -F, -lane 'print unless $seen{$F[1]}++' data.txt` you can also do `perl -F, -lane '$seen{$F[1]}++||print' data.txt`. `:P`

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the delimiter to `,` (the default delimiter is whitespace) and use the correct column (`$2`) for the "seen" array.

```
$ awk -F, '!seen[$2]++' file
10.4.14.1,201s-1-S
10.4.17.1,40-MDF-S
10.4.24.1,MDF-S
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `sort` for this:

```
$ sort -t, -k2 -u file
10.4.14.1,201s-1-S
10.4.17.1,40-MDF-S
10.4.24.1,MDF-S
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -rn '1!G;/^[^,]*(,[^\n]*)\n.*\1/!P;h' file
```

If the second field in the current line is not a duplicate print the current line.